# Code unique observations based on condition

Tags: r, subset

Say I have a data set

```
car_manu    owner
ford         1
toyota       1
ford         2
ford         3
ford         3
ford         3
```

I'd like to make a variable that says if they're a 'one car owner' -  this would mean owner 2 is one car owner. I know this would use the `unique(df$owner)` but I'm not sure to assign this to an observation.

The expected output is

```
 car_manu owner     type
     ford     1 multicar   
   toyota     1 multicar
     ford     2   onecar
     ford     3 multicar
     ford     3 multicar
     ford     3 multicar
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `type
multicar
multicar
onecar
multicar
multicar
multicar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R possibility

```
tab <- tabulate(df$owner)
cbind(df, type = rep(ifelse(tab == 1L, "onecar", "multicar"), tab))
#   car_manu owner     type
# 1     ford     1 multicar
# 2   toyota     1 multicar
# 3     ford     2   onecar
# 4     ford     3 multicar
# 5     ford     3 multicar
# 6     ford     3 multicar
```

where

```
df <- structure(list(car_manu = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ford", 
"toyota"), class = "factor"), owner = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
)), .Names = c("car_manu", "owner"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(owner) %>%
       mutate(onecar = ifelse(n()==1, 1, 0))
```

Comment: you can just change the ifelse : onecar = ifelse(n()==1 & rich[1] =="rich", 1, 0)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a column based on the number of observations using 'owner' as a grouping variable, then we could use `data.table`.  We change the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`). Grouped by 'owner', we check the condition  `if(.N==1)` it will be 'one car owner' or else 'multi-car' and assign the output to a new column 'owner_type'

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, owner_type :=if(.N==1) 'one-car' else 'multi-car', owner]
```

Or without using the `if/else` condition, we can create a logical vector (`.N!=1`) by 'owner', add 1 to it and use that as numeric index to replace that with 'one-car', 'multi-car'.

```
  setDT(df1)[, owner_type:=c('one-car', 'multi-car')[(.N!=1)+1] , owner]
  df1
  #   car_manu owner owner_type
  #1:     ford     1  multi-car
  #2:   toyota     1  multi-car
  #3:     ford     2    one-car
  #4:     ford     3  multi-car
  #5:     ford     3  multi-car
  #6:     ford     3  multi-car
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base and given the dataframe called `d` you can use an `ifelse` and the `ave` function as shown below:

```
d$type=ifelse(ave(d$owner,d$owner,FUN=length)==1,"one car","multicar")
d
  #   car_manu owner type
  #1:     ford     1  multi-car
  #2:   toyota     1  multi-car
  #3:     ford     2    one-car
  #4:     ford     3  multi-car
  #5:     ford     3  multi-car
  #6:     ford     3  multi-car
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple base `R`

```
d$type<-apply(d,1,function(x){length(which(d$owner==x[2]))})
```

As I am in process of learning `R`, this might not be one of the most efficient methods but is easy to use and understand.